# Finding sides of triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Given :
$$\triangle ABC$$
$$M \in AB,N \in BC ,P \in AC$$ are the points at which the incircle crosses the triangle
$$MN=3\sqrt{10}$$
$$NP=2\sqrt{20}$$
$$PM=10$$
I have to find the sides of the triangle. 
I have no idea how to solve this exercise, I can't use the formula $$r = \frac{a+b-c}{2}$$ since the triangle isn't right(doesn't have right angle), nor I can prove it.
The answer from my textbook is :
$$AB = 32$$
$$BC = 16$$
$$CA=24$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\angle{MNB}=\angle{NMB}=\angle{MPN}$, we have
$$BM=BN=\frac{MN/2}{\cos{\angle{MPN}}}$$
You can find $\cos\angle{MPN}$ by the law of cosines. Similarly do for $AM=AP,CP=CN$.

Comment: It's clear that $$\angle{MNB}=\angle{NMB}$$, since $$BM = BN$$ but how did you get that they are equal to $$\angle{MPN}$$ ?

Comment: @Planet_Earth: Alternate segment theorem. See, for example, [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/).

Answer (score 1):

One can even do WITHOUT law of cosines, us the law of sines. Here $r$ is the radius of the in-circle. Check that $\angle MNI= \angle  B/2$

$\frac{MN}{sin(180^0-B)}=\frac{r}{sin\frac{B}{2}}$

So it stands that $\frac{MN}{cos(B/2)}=\frac{PM}{cos(A/2)}=\frac{PN}{cos(C/2)}=\frac{PN}{sin((A+B)/2)}=2r$

Now solving is easy..3 equations 2 unknowns..